# Sorting Algorithm stops when it finds a correct condition

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

I am writing a javascript code which will sort arrays in ascending order. But whenever my code meets the correct condition which is `arr[1] < arr[2]`, it stops the loop and prompts the message `Congratulations!! This Group is Sorted` By the way, I am using jquery also because I made a little game that you can sort all the numbers to ascending order and check if it is sorted or not.

I am not sure if the click event is responsible for the loop to stop. I am really confused with this. Can someone help me?

Here is the code snippet from my project:

HTML

```
<ul id="sort">
   <!--Generated Numbers using javascript-->
</ul>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sort").sortable();
    $("#sort").disableSelection();

        // var elemArr = document.getElementsByClassName("sort-ui");
        // var arr = jQuery.makeArray(elemArr);
        // arr = arr.map(data => data.innerHTML);
        var arr = [];

    function generateNum(){
        var min=1;
        var max=12;
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (+max - +min)) + +min;
        // document.write("Random Number Generated : " + random );
    }

    function storeToArray() {
        var i = 0;
        var ul = document.getElementById("sort");
        var li;
        while(i < 12) {
            var rec = generateNum();

            arr[i] = rec;
            li = document.createElement("li");
            li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr[i]));
            ul.appendChild(li);
            ++i;
        }
    }

    storeToArray();

    $(".btn-check").on("click", function(){
        var elemArr = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
        var arrCheck = jQuery.makeArray(elemArr);
        arrCheck = arrCheck.map(data => data.innerHTML);
        var int;
        var len = arrCheck.length;
        console.log(arrCheck);
        for(int = 0; int < len-1; i++) {
            if(arrCheck[int] > arrCheck[int+1]){
                alert("This Group is Not Sorted");
            } else {
                alert("Congratulations!! This Group is Sorted");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

CSS (For you to visualize)

```
#sort {
    list-style: none;
    width: 430px;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 315px;
}

#sort li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: yellow;
    font: 600 16px/100px "Arial";
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    border: 3px solid white;
}

.button-c {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Can you create fiddle for this?

Comment: The issuse is there if(arrCheck[int] > arrCheck[int+1]). Just add one else if(arrCheck[int] == arrCheck[int+1]) { continue } else ...

Comment: now my problem is it wont stop looping @AshutoshSharma

Comment: hi @SujeetSinha, here is the pen for this -> https://codepen.io/faye-ylaya/pen/mdyxEXg

Comment: error was in i++ put in++ there

Comment: thank you! but it never stopped looping. @AshutoshSharma. Already made changes in my fiddle already

Comment: @AlexRufus, please check the answer and mark it as so, if it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation of the sort function was incorrect. You didn't use the `break` keyword and your numbers were in string format, so you need to parse them for comparison.

```
function isSorted(arrCheck) {
    var sortVal = true;
    var len = arrCheck.length;
    console.log(arrCheck);
    for(int = 0; int < len-1; int++) {
        if(parseInt(arrCheck[int]) > parseInt(arrCheck[int+1])) {
            sortVal = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return sortVal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is mistake in for loop i++ *for(int = 0; int < len-1; i++)* , It should be int++

```
let arrCheck = [1, 3 , 3, 4]
let len = arrCheck.length
for(let int = 0; int < len-1; int++) {
  if(arrCheck[int] > arrCheck[int+1]){
      alert("This Group is Not Sorted");
  } else {
      alert("Congratulations!! This Group is Sorted");
  }
}
```

Comment: updated the fiddle though https://codepen.io/faye-ylaya/pen/mdyxEXg

Comment: Its working fine, there is no infinite loop. You must be clicking on alert box OK too fast.

Comment: updated my fiddle again. it displays the wrong output. I made the loop into a function and returned a boolean value : https://codepen.io/faye-ylaya/pen/mdyxEXg